# unexpected this value after using bind already

Tags: javascript

I really don't figure out why in the foreach(where console.log prints) this becomes Window object. Thanks in advance.

the code detects hover events, and it reads range slider value then.

HTML,

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="10" id="rangeR">
```

JS,

```
var ColorDispatcher = function() {
this.rgbColorArray=new Array(0,0,0);
};

ColorDispatcher.prototype = {
hoverHandler:function () {
     var SliderArray=new Array(document.getElementById("rangeR"));
     SliderArray.forEach(function sliderHandler(element, index, array){         
     console.log(this);
             element.addEventListener("change", function() {
                 if(index==0){//R
                     this.rgbColorArray[0]=element.value;                       
                 }
             });

     });


},

};
var dispatcher = new ColorDispatcher();
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover',dispatcher.hoverHandler.bind(dispatcher));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 'this' keyword returns the window object within an object's prototype in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224620/the-this-keyword-returns-the-window-object-within-an-objects-prototype-in-jav)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bind` sets the value of `this` for the function it is called on. When you call `dispatcher.hoverHandler`, then `this` is `dispatcher`

This line:

> ```
> console.log(this);
> ```

… is not part of `dispatcher.hoverHandler`

It is part of the sliderHandler function that you pass to `SliderArray.forEach`.

If you want to pass a different `this` value, then you should do it using the **second** argument to `forEach` (after the function).

Answer (score -1):

Why you named the callback function ?

I think instead of pass an anonymous function you create a global function and then the 'this' is window.

Try remove the name 'sliderHandler'.

Comment: "Why you named the callback function ?" — It is useful to have a name for a function when looking at a stacktrace. (It also allows the function to be called recursively, but that isn't happening here).

Comment: "you create a global function" — **No!** Named function expressions do not automatically create globals. They don't even create a variable with their name expect inside their own scope. (This is different from function declarations which create a variable with their name in the scope they are created in)

Comment: My bad ^^ i didnt know that you can name the anonymous function